# How to replace enum property name

Tags: python, enums

I want to remove underscores in enum name but this code leads to recursion error, how to fix it efficiently?

```
from enum import Enum

class A(Enum):
    ABC = '0'
    OTC = '1'
    _1T = '2'

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self.name.replace('_', '')
```

Comment: The edits to this question are being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424562/should-an-initial-solution-to-a-problem-be-posted-as-an-answer-instead-of-inclu#424562)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
return self.name.replace('_', '')
```

to:

```
return self.__dict__['_name_'].replace('_', '')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access the underlying name property as `_name_`: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-sunder-names

So you can change

```
return self.name.replace('_', '')
```

to

```
return self._name_.replace('_', '')
```